# using Stimulsoft in intellij idea and java language

Tags: java, intellij-idea, stimulsoft

I want to add [Stimulsoft Report](https://www.stimulsoft.com/en) in [Intellij Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), but I don't know how to configure and install and use this reporting tools into the [Intellij Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Could anyone please help me?

---

I visit the **[stimulsoft](https://www.stimulsoft.com/en)**, but I didn't find appropriate sample for up and running with this software, and when I found sample it didn't contain "jar" file and it wasn't complete.

Answer (score 1):

## If using a build automation tool like Gradle or Maven for your IntelliJ project

1. Search for the package needed. For example if you're trying to `import com.stimulsoft.report.StiReport;`, you might use [Stimulsoft Reports Report](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.stimulsoft/stimulsoft-reports-report/2019.3.3)
2. Choose the version you want (likely most recent).
3. Click the tab for your tool (e.g. Gradle or Maven).
4. Copy the text in to your `build.gradle`, `pom.xml`, or the like.

At least for Gradle, you might need to make small changes to match how your project is set up. E.g.:

```
Change:
compile group: 'com.stimulsoft', name: 'stimulsoft-reports-report', version: '2019.3.3'

to:
providedCompile 'com.stimulsoft:stimulsoft-reports-report:2019.3.3'
```

## If not using a build automation tool

1. Add the .jar's to the project as library(ies) via File > Project Structure > Libraries > +
2. Add the library(ies) to the module(s) via File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies tab > +